# sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) method returns strange results

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3, tableview

In my viewController with tableView in it I have the list of objects fetched from Core Data Database using fetchedResultsController. I've grouped all fetched results by section. It works fine, I've implemented the following methods to enable A-Z sectionIndexes which appears on the right side of the TableView:

```
 func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
     let indexTitles = self.fetchedResultsController.sectionIndexTitles

        return indexTitles

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
         return self.fetchedResultsController.section(forSectionIndexTitle: title, at: index)
    }
```

I also have this declaration of `fetchedResultsController`

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Object>!

 self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context!, sectionNameKeyPath: "project.group.name", cacheName: nil)
```

sectionIndexTitles works fine while I have values for group.name in English in my Core Data database, but when I have group.name values in another language (or English mixed with not English) `sectionIndexTitles` is showing (returning) me English letters , but for Non English letters it returns me question marks or English letters.

for example it returns the array like this `["A", "B", "F", "G", "R", "S", "A", "E"]` , instead of returning the array like this  `["A", "B", "F", "G", "R", "S", "Letter in another language", "Letter in another language"]`.
I've changed language scheme and it returns `["A", "B", "F", "G", "R", "S", "?", "?"]`.
It substitutes non english letters with English letters or showing "?", instead of showing value in another language.

[image]

Not sure if it is a bug? Or maybe it can not show letters in different languages. Where can be the problem and how to solve it?

I'm using Swift 3, Xcode 8.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, for Russian language it returned me ! instead of characters. So I performed this solution:

```
override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    if let sections = fetchedResultsController?.sections {
        var sectionTitles: [String] = []

        for section in sections {
            sectionTitles.append(String(describing: section.name.first!))
        }
        return sectionTitles
    }

return fetchedResultsController?.sectionIndexTitles
}
```

I think this can be used for most of cases